# Is renderer.render() blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to take a screen shot after every rendered frame completes, but I'm finding that some screen shots are duplicates, so I'm wondering if I might be saving the screen shot before the render is finished. Thus...

1. Does renderer.render() block until it finishes rendering?
2. If not, is there a way to know via callback or event when it is complete?

Comment: Is there a significant change between every rendered frame, or how do you know it has not rendered the next frame when screenshots look the same?

Comment: The animation is of an object moving horizontally across the screen at a fixed rate, specifically `object.position.x -= 40`.  The change is several pixels so it is visibly significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a render test with 50k cubes which on my laptop takes about 6-10 seconds.

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/1ma18gLf/

The function does block based on the test. Use the browser console to watch the result and see the base64 image.

The question then becomes does webGL paint to the canvas separately regardless of what JavaScript is doing.

You could try a manual clear before the render:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
renderer.autoClear = false;

//In your render loop:

renderer.clear();
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Comment: There's been two vote downs on this. If there is a better method of answering the question, I'm genuinely curious. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer was very helpful in its definitiveness. Thank you!